# distance between mobiles system

Tags: mobile, geolocation, gps

I'm developing something for my mobile and wanted to implement a feature that will show other mobile devices that are near you(changeable radius if it's possible) that have the same app by using wifi or gps, whatever is better.
How do I do something like that(reference to a great guide/site is great)? Is there a some sort of a ready plugin or something ^^?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) The app reads the GPS Position of a user ID and send it to your server and store the most recent one

2) The App connect to server and reads the position of all users, or all users within aproximate distance from current device position GPS.

Fpr aproximate distance calculate the distance between two lat/lon coordinates. ios and android have built in functions. Otherwise the are easy to self implement.